# How to access to a function from world.js?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, screenshot

I'm trying to access to this.addScreenshotToReport from a function of world.js

This is the code I been trying to export the world.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
var worldPath = path.join(config.paths.root, '../support/world')
this.World = require(worldPath).World;
}
```

And i put this.addScreenshotToReport() to access in that specific tunction

This is the code from world.js:

```
function CustomWorld({attach, parameters}) {

this.waitForTestController = testControllerHolder.get()
    .then(function(tc) {
        return testController = tc;
    });

this.attach = attach;

this.setBrowser = function() {
    if (parameters.browser === undefined) {
        return 'chrome';
    } else {
        return parameters.browser;
    }
};

this.addScreenshotToReport = function() {
    if (process.argv.includes('--format') || process.argv.includes('-f') || process.argv.includes('--format-options')) {
        testController.takeScreenshot()
            .then(function(screenshotPath) {
                const imgInBase64 = base64Img.base64Sync(screenshotPath);
                const imageConvertForCuc = imgInBase64.substring(imgInBase64.indexOf(',') + 1);
                return attach(imageConvertForCuc, 'image/png');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.warn('The screenshot was not attached to the report');
            });
    } else {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(null);
        });
    }
};
```

The actual output is:
TypeError: this.addScreenshotToReport is not a function

Comment: I have no idea what your code is about and all, but it seems like you ran into a `this` hell. Try to `console.log` `this` before you call `addScreenshotToReport` to have a better idea of what `this` is in that context.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear. I'm just trying to get access to - this.addScreenshotToReport - wich is in world.js file. So I'm in an other .js file where i want to 'import' the functions from world.js. I also tried with this code -const world = require('../support/world.js') - but I have the same Error

Comment: When you put "require" you don't pass the '.js' part of the path, (I'm assuming your work with NodeJS because of `module.exports` and `require()`), try removing that .js and see if it works. Also the keyword "this" is very weird and can behave in complex ways sometimes, that's why I suggested you to check `what the hell is "this"` at debug time before calling functions from it